# Meteor.js embedded collections

Tags: meteor

Data model:

```
{
    name: "Some name",
    items: ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"]
}
```

I want to publish all the `name` fields into a collection (this I can do), let's call it `names`, and once the user selects something from `names`, publish the items array into another Meteor collection called `items`.

The reason for this is that I need `names` to be always available and `items` should only be relevant to the user's selection.

How can this be achieved? Maybe there's another way to do this, e.g. selectively update only a part of an item in a collection?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common model in Meteor and Mongo. You can solve it in two major ways.

1. If the number of items per name is going to be small, just put them into an array inside the name document. They will be automatically available to you whenever you load a name.
2. If the number of items per name could be very large, then create two collections, `Names` and `Items`. In the the `Items` collection include a key `nameId` and fill it with the name. Then when you load a name document you can simply find the related items with `Items.find({ nameId: _idOfMyNameDocument })`

You may also find the [reywood:publish-composite](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) package helpful.